# pass java variable in jsp:param

Tags: jsp, jspinclude, param

```
 <%!  
    String str = "prerna";  
  %>  

 <jsp:include page="index.html">
      <jsp:param name="type1" value=<%=str%> >
      </jsp:param>  
 </jsp:include>
```

I want to pass a java variable in the param tag,but i am not sure how to do it.

I also want to access it in `index.html`.
Can anyone suggest me the way to do it ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Just put it in `value` directly.

```
<jsp:include page="index.html">
    <jsp:param name="type1" value="prerna" />
</jsp:include>
```

Or use JSTL `<c:set>` to set it and EL `${}` to get it.

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
...
<c:set var="type1" value="prerna" />
...
<jsp:include page="index.html">
    <jsp:param name="type1" value="${type1}" />
</jsp:include>
```

And if your included page is a jsp, then you can use it as `${param.type1}`

Comment: Rename `index.html` to `index.jsp` and use `${param.type1}` to get it.

Comment: I want to retrive a data from database using rs.getString(1).that value i want to pass it in param

Comment: Create a DAO class which does the DB interaction job and returns normal Java objects. Import and call the DAO class in a servlet class. Let the servlet put it in request scope and forward to JSP. Finally use servlet URL instead of JSP URL.

Comment: actually I think i am not clear...I am diaplaying user topics in my jsp page....there i have retrieved a user id.i am including post a comment jsp page where i need that particular id.that is why i am asking to put java variable in that param tag

Comment: Well, probably you've read too many roseindia.net articles? :)

Comment: <%
        String str="prafful";
        %>


        <c:set var="type1" value='<%=str%>' />

<jsp:include page="index1.jsp">
    <jsp:param name="type1" value="${type1}" />
</jsp:include>is working .thks for the solution

Comment: <jsp:include page="index3.jsp">
    <jsp:param name="id" value='<%=str%>'></jsp:param>
</jsp:include> is also working

Comment: kk thks for ur advice but i am new to EL can you tell me the way to pass the java variable....i am not understanding it at all

Comment: Just read JSP/Servlet books/tutorials. Do **not** use roseindia.net. That site is cluttered of bad practices that you don't see the difference between good and bad anymore.

Comment: Hover `[jsp]` tag below your question until a box pops, click `info` link on the popbox. It leads to our JSP wiki page. At the bottom you can find links to good tutorials.

Answer (score 5):

Request parameters can be passed by using `<jsp: param>`
One can pass the parameter names and values to the forwarded file by using a `<jsp: param>` tag

Sample e.g :

**HTML :**

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<jsp:forward page="ssParameters.jsp">
  <jsp:param name="myParam" value="Amar Patel"/>
  <jsp:param name="Age" value="15"/>
</jsp:forward>
</body>
</html>
```

`<jsp:param>`  tag is used to pass the name and values to the targeted file. These parameters will be retrieved by the targeted file by using `request.getParameter()` method. In this way one can pass and retrieve the parameters.

```
This page had a parameter forwarded to it:<br>
  <b>Name:</b> <%= request.getParameter("myParam") %><br>
  <b>Age:</b> <%= request.getParameter("Age") %>
```

Comment: i want to pass a java variable

Answer (score 3):

To pass parameters to a jsp jstl:

```
/* JSP PARENT */

<jsp:include page="../../templates/options.jsp">                    
    <jsp:param name="action" value="${myValue}"/>       
</jsp:include>


/* JSP CHILD (options.jsp)*/

<div id="optionButtons left">       
    <span>${param.action}</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

just but the <%=str%> in double quotes this should work , i hope this is an answer to your question.

```
<%!  
    String str = "prerna";  
%>  

<jsp:include page="index.html">
      <jsp:param name="type1" value="<%=str%>" />  
</jsp:include>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `request.setAttribute()` you can pass the Java variable to the JSP.

```
 <%  
    String str = "prerna";

    request.setAttribute("myVar",str);
  %>  

 <jsp:include page="index.html">
      <jsp:param name="type1" value="${myVar}" >
      </jsp:param>  
 </jsp:include>
```