# jsp request.getParameter

Tags: java, jsp

Edited, Still this is not working exactly, but I need to set a page_type on each page of a website. That page_type needs to be checked by some java and do code based on the page_type.
The problem is, the if else statements are not being done correctly. Nothing happens because the parameter doesn't seem to be placed.
main page where page_type is being set:

```
<div id="DYK_area">
 <jsp:include page="/imgs/random_dyk.jsp" flush="true">
 <jsp:param name="Page_type" value="prenatalOverviewArea"></jsp:param>
 </jsp:include>
</div>
```

Where the code is being checked

```
<% String pageType = request.getParameter("page_type")==null?"": request.getParameter("page_type"); 
String image_name="";   
    if(pageType.equals("prenatalOverviewArea")){
        int random = (int )(Math.random() * 10 + 1);
        image_name= "/images/did_you_know/dyk_p_" + random + ".png";
    }
    else if(pageType.equals("prenatalNorm")){
        int random = (int )(Math.random() * 25 + 1);
        image_name= "/images/did_you_know/dyk_p_" + random + ".png";
    }
    else if(pageType.equals("overviewArea")){
        int random = (int )(Math.random() * 20 + 1);
        image_name= "/images/did_you_know/dyk_" + random + ".png";
    }
    else if(pageType.equals("overviewNorm")){
        int random = (int )(Math.random() * 45 + 1);
        image_name= "/images/did_you_know/dyk_" + random + ".png";
    }

if(!image_name.equals("")){
%>

<img id="dyk_random" src="<%=image_name%>"/>

<%}%>
```

Comment: What's `Page_type`? `request.getParameter` reads the param but it doesn't automagically assign it to a variable. Use something like this instead: `String type = request.getParameter("Page_type");` and use the `type` variable in your conditions.

Comment: I am trying to set the page_type to the page I am on so the if statement will see what code to run. I have 0 exp with java, so this is all new  ={>)

Comment: Also, while using scriptlets like this, refrain from using the `==` operator while comparing `String` objects. Use the `equals` method instead. `==` or `eq` is alright in the JSP Expression Language but not in scriptlets.

Comment: These are good tips, but nothing has changed in what is displayed. I know too little about java, i may need a working example of this.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5444083/1065197. By the way, stop using scriplets, their usage is highly discouraged, instead use EL and JSTL. More info: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3177733/1065197

Comment: Wow, this looks a bit confusing, maybe a bit above my pay grade  ={>)

Comment: Try isolating the problem. First, change the name of the `<jsp:param>` from `Page_Type` to `pageType`. Second, in `/imgs/random_dyk.jsp` page, remove all the scriplets and just add `${param.pageType}`. Clean and build your project and redeploy it, then add in comments the result displayed in the page.

Comment: The problem seems to be the if statements. Either the param is being brought in wrong, type.equals doesnt work, or the string is wrong.

Comment: Move the logic to the controller, to many if-else replace with a map create the interface and call it for each instance of the map entry. Remember to always code to interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `type` variable to get value from request parameter but in `if` condition you are using `Page_type`

***INCLUDE JSP LIKE THIS***

```
<div id="DYK_area">
   <jsp:include page="/imgs/random_dyk.jsp" flush="true">
     <jsp:param name="Page_type" value="prenatalOverviewArea" />
   </jsp:include>
</div>
```

***ON INCLUDED JSP***

```
<%
    System.out.println("Page type is : "+request.getParameter("Page_type"));
    String Page_type = request.getParameter("Page_type");
    if(Page_type.equalsIgnoreCase("prenatalOverviewArea")){
        int random = (int )(Math.random() * 10 + 1);
        image_name= "/images/did_you_know/dyk_" + random + ".png";
    }

    else if(Page_type.equalsIgnoreCase("prenatalNorm")){
        int random = (int )(Math.random() * 25 + 1);
        image_name= "/images/did_you_know/dyk_p_" + random + ".png";
    }
%><img id="dyk_random" src="<%=image_name%>"/>
```

Comment: that looks like a typo

Comment: This didnt exactly do much for the code unfortunately (thanks tho, I did learn a little bit for this response tho!). I made a few changes with my example, but its pretty much the same.

Comment: -1: This won't solve OP's problem, note that basically this is what he/she is already doing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that the code is correct in /imgs/random_dyk.jsp. You use the variable Page_type although it doesn't exist.

You should initialize it before, at line `request.getParameter("Page_type");`like this:

```
<%! String xxx = request.getParameter("Page_type"); %>
```

then ,

```
<% if(xxx.equals("prenatalOverviewArea")){
...
```

Comment: -1: OP already does this here: `String type = request.getParameter("Page_type");`.

Comment: I made a few adjustment, but still nothing is working correctly.

Comment: I didn't see the line `String pageType = request.getParameter("page_type")==null?"": request.getParameter("page_type");`

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked, thanks anyways guys, you all got me closer at the least!

```
<div id="DYK_area">
 <jsp:include page="/imgs/random_dyk.jsp" flush="true">
 <jsp:param name="page_type" value="prenatalOverviewArea"></jsp:param>
 </jsp:include>
</div>

<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" language="java"  errorPage="" %>

<% String pageType = request.getParameter("page_type")==null?"": request.getParameter("page_type"); 
String image_name="";   
    if(pageType.equals("prenatalOverviewArea")){
        int random = (int )(Math.random() * 10 + 1);
        image_name= "/images/did_you_know/dyk_p_" + random + ".png";
    }
    else if(pageType.equals("prenatalNorm")){
        int random = (int )(Math.random() * 25 + 1);
        image_name= "/images/did_you_know/dyk_p_" + random + ".png";
    }
    else if(pageType.equals("overviewArea")){
        int random = (int )(Math.random() * 20 + 1);
        image_name= "/images/did_you_know/dyk_" + random + ".png";
    }
    else if(pageType.equals("overviewNorm")){
        int random = (int )(Math.random() * 45 + 1);
        image_name= "/images/did_you_know/dyk_" + random + ".png";
    }

if(!image_name.equals("")){
%>

<img id="dyk_random" src="<%=image_name%>"/>

<%}%>
```